# Combine Text in ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have a table using Google Sheets. It has three columns that will always have a null value or a specific value for that column. Each line will have one, two, or three values; it will never have three null values on one line. In the fourth column, I want an ArrayFormula that will combine those values and separate the values with a comma if there is more than one.

Here is a photo of what I am trying to accomplish.
[image]

I've tried several ideas so far and this formula is the closest I've gotten so far but it's still not quite working correctly; I think it is treating each column as an array before joining rather than doing the function line by line. I'm using the LEN function rather than A2="" or ISBLANK(A2) because columns A-C are ArrayFormulas as well. I realize this probably isn't the most efficient formula to use but I think it covers every possibility. I'm definitely open to other ideas as well.

```
={"Focus";
  ArayFormula(
    IFS(
      $A$2:$A="", "",
      (LEN(A2:A)>0 & LEN(B2:B)>0 & LEN(C2:C)>0), TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, A2:A, B2:B, C2:C),
      (LEN(A2:A)>0 & LEN(B2:B)>0 & LEN(C2:C)=0), TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, A2:A, B2:B),
      (LEN(A2:A)>0 & LEN(B2:B)=0 & LEN(C2:C)>0), TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, A2:A, C2:C),
      (LEN(A2:A)=0 & LEN(B2:B)>0 & LEN(C2:C)>0), TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, B2:B, C2:C),
      (LEN(A2:A)>0 & LEN(B2:B)=0 & LEN(C2:C)=0), A2:A,
      (LEN(A2:A)=0 & LEN(B2:B)>0 & LEN(C2:C)=0), B2:B,
      (LEN(A2:A)=0 & LEN(B2:B)=0 & LEN(C2:C)>0), C2:C
    )
  )
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this with Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Sample File**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zE4-mDvZ75xHNvgHdEi-BroUYofo7C1r6hQu_hZcIDo/edit#gid=300833075)

Please try:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:C,ROW(A2:C)<=MAX(IF(LEN(A2:C),ROW(A2:C)*COLUMN(A2:C)^0,0)))),,2^99)))," ",", "))`

Notes:

- The formula will work incorrectly if some names have space inside: like "Aston Martin"
- So if you have spaces, please try this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(A2:C," ",char(9)),ROW(A2:C)<=MAX(IF(LEN(A2:C),ROW(A2:C)*COLUMN(A2:C)^0,0)))),,2^99)))," ",", "),
CHAR(9)," "))`

**EDIT**

Noticed the shorter variant (without `*COLUMN(A2:C)^0`) will work:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(A2:C," ",char(9)),ROW(A2:C)<=MAX(IF(LEN(A2:C),ROW(A2:C),0)))),,2^99)))," ",", "),
CHAR(9)," "))`

Notes:

- I used an old trick to join strings with an `array-formula`. See [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VY157ykKsCVDqEKDBp3oAVaG0LTXAz8wUCggCrFXMDM/edit#gid=1105736583)

---

## Explanations

If you like to understand any tiered formula, the best way is to split it by parts:

**Part 1. Filter the data**

1. `FILTER(any_columns,ROW(A2:C)<=MAX(IF(LEN(A2:C),ROW(A2:C)*COLUMN(A2:C)^0,0)))`. this is my way to limit the data range.
2. The range is open, means it starts from the second row (`A2`) and
   ends in any row.
3. I want to get the limited array in this step to reduce work that the formula should do. This is done with a condition, `if`.
4. `ROW(A2:C)` must be less or equal to the max row of data.
   `MAX(IF(LEN(A2:C), some_rows)` gives the max row.
5. `If(len..` part checks if a cell has some text inside it.
6. Note `some_rows` part:
   `MAX(IF(LEN(A2:C),ROW(A2:C)*COLUMN(A2:C)^0,0)))),,2^99)))`.
   `ROW(A2:C)` must be multiplied by columns, because `filter` formula
   takes only one row into its condition. That is why I multiply by
   `COLUMN(A2:C)^0` which is columns with 1s. **Edit.** Now noticed,
   that the formula works fine without `*COLUMN(A2:C)^0`, so it's an
   overkill.

**Part 2. Join the text**

7. `query` formula has 3 arguments: data, query_text, and a number_of_header_rows.
8. `data` is made with a filter.
9. `query_text` is empty, which gives us equivalent to select all
   (`"select *"`).
10. And the number of rows of a header is some big number (`2^99`).
     This    is a trick: when a `query` has more headers then one row,
     it will    join them with space.
11. After a union is made, `transpose` function will convert the result back to the column.

**Part 3. Substitute and trim**

12. The function `trim` deletes extra spaces.
13. Then we replace spaces with the delimiter: `", "`. That is why the
     formula needs to be modified if spaces are in strings. Correct
     result: "Ford, Aston Martin". Incorrect: "Ford, Aston, Martin". But
     if we previously replace spaces with some char (`char(9)` is Tab),
     then we do not replace it in this step.

Comment: I don't know how it works but it works perfectly for what I am trying to accomplish! Thank you very much. Could you please explain how that works? And also why it does not work if the name has a space inside?

Comment: Hi, @MattCampbell, I've made an edit. Hope, it's clear. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: That's amazing! That makes much more sense now. Thanks a ton!