# How Can I make an Arrayformula of an already complex Arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

This type of question has been asked many times on here (I know), and I've tried to translate half a dozen answers into my particular formula without success ([like the query smush header trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48456012/combine-text-in-arrayformula)). I guess I don't know how or where to implement it into my already pretty complex formula (which parses a multi-line block of opening hours text into a single start/end time format for each day of the week (and secondary times if present). All of my attempts either don't work, or the result of the calculation of the first row is repeated down the entire column.

I've backed all my attempts up, and will share the base formula that I'd like to ultimately be "arrayformula'd" down the entire column (for thousands of rows).

[Here's the Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-UbeKx6830Vt5dnVS9iPN0me9j6A6UBFpiuZdifIKDA/edit?usp=sharing)

And here's the base formula thus far:

```
=if(isblank($A3:$A),,iferror(
  regexreplace(
    concatenate(
      arrayformula(
        text(
          split(
            INDEX(
              REGEXEXTRACT(
                regexreplace($A3:$A,"–","-"),
                "(\s?" & B$1 & ":\s)((\d?\d:\d\d\s[AMP]*\s?\W\s\d?\d:\d\d\s[AMP]{2})|(Closed)|(Open\s24\shours))"
              ),1,2 
            ),"-",true,true
          ),"HH:MM-"
        )
      )
    ),"(\d\d:\d\d\-\d\d:\d\d)\-","$1"
  ),
))
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

***EDIT**: I've been asked to clarify what the formula is doing. The formula is parsing a block of text which contains the business hours of a business from Monday to Sunday into a machine readable format (which I will be importing into a database). If the business has blocks of time (like a restaurant that opens for lunch, has a break, and then reopens for dinner), the formula in the adjacent cell accounts for that too).*

Comment: I'm on vacation, but I'll add a clarifying question that may help others in helping you. What do your results mean? I looked at your sheet quickly and "17:00 - 21:00" had no evident meaning. I suggest you make the meaning of those results (e.g., mon1, mon2, etc.) clear in your post.

Comment: They are times (in 24 hour format). 17:00 to 21:00 = 5pm to 9pm on Monday (the column that it's under). Each of the 14 columns (mon1 to sun2) is a parsed out result of the far left column (which is a block of ALL times for the entire week)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(B2:O2, QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,2), ",;"))<>"", 
 COUNTIFS(
 INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,1), 
 INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,1), 
      ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))))),
 "<="&ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))))))&"♣"&LOWER(
  LEFT(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,1), 3))&COLUMN(A:B)&"♣"&
 SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,2), ",;"),,1), "–"),  "hh:mm")),,9^9)),
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(IFERROR(SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,2), ",;"),,2), "–")), "hh:mm")),,9^9))}, 
 "00:00 00:00", ), " ", "-"), 
 COUNTIFS(
 INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,1), 
 INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,1), 
      ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))))),
 "<="&ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))))))&"♣"&LOWER(
  LEFT(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,1), 3))&COLUMN(A:B))), "♣"), 
 "select max(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A3:A)+ROW(A3)-1)), 0)))
```

[image]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(B2:O2, IFNA(VLOOKUP({""; ROW(A3:A)}, QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,2), ",;"))<>"", 
 LOWER(LEFT(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, IF(A3:A="",,
 REGEXREPLACE(A3:A, "^|(\n)", "$1"&ROW(A3:A)&"♣"))), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,1), 5))&COLUMN(A:B)&"♣"&
 SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,2), ",;"),,1), "–"),  "hh:mm")),,9^9)),
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(IFERROR(SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,2), ",;"),,2), "–")), "hh:mm")),,9^9))}, 
 "00:00 00:00", ), "Closed 00:00", "Closed"), " ", "-"), 
 LOWER(LEFT(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, IF(A3:A="",,
 REGEXREPLACE(A3:A, "^|(\n)", "$1"&ROW(A3:A)&"♣"))), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,1), 5))&COLUMN(A:B))), "♣"), 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), COLUMN(B:O), 0)), ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A3:A)+ROW(A3)-1)), 0)))
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NjuKyR3S9vNocTKpgA9cb91vWyJ5uRuBNdYH21kwd9k/edit#gid=0)

---

### FIX:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(B2:O2, IFNA(VLOOKUP({""; ROW(A3:A)}, QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,2), ",;"))<>"", 
 LOWER(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, IF(A3:A="",,
 REGEXREPLACE(A3:A, "^|(\n)", "$1"&ROW(A3:A)&"♣"))), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,1), "\d+♣..."))&COLUMN(A:B)&"♣"&
 SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,2), ",;"),,1), "–"),  "hh:mm")),,9^9)),
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(IFERROR(SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, A3:A), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,2), ",;"),,2), "–")), "hh:mm")),,9^9))}, 
 "00:00 00:00", ), "Closed 00:00", "Closed"), " ", "-"), 
 LOWER(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, IF(A3:A="",,
 REGEXREPLACE(A3:A, "^|(\n)", "$1"&ROW(A3:A)&"♣"))), CHAR(10))), ": ", ),,1), "\d+♣..."))&COLUMN(A:B))), "♣"), 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), COLUMN(B:O), 0)), ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A:A="", ROW(A:A))))), 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. I wasn't expecting to get a formula that filled the columns AND the rows. This is insane. I'm not even going to begin to try to understand this one...but thank you.

Comment: I just realized that I screwed up when I created the example spreadsheet. The source data that gets imported from a JSON file does not have a trailing ";" on the last line (Monday). Which line would I need to alter to have the formula work without a trailing semi colon? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15bgF4ARzt3Z2qqFLxl8FzEyWYqRtsNIB_58H-R_cpMc/edit#gid=0 EDIT: Actually, I don't think missing trailing semi colon is the problem. I just can't get the formula to work on a different sheet.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help. However...if there is more than one blank row, the formula begins to break down. Unfortunately, my source data has many blank hours rows (not all business hours are known). [Here's a sheet with real source data to show you what I mean](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bA2D43Gs5V7nP4iAfF5U-vI4Fi3Cx_KvLW9OW8-IIEU/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another suggestion, which is shorter and accomplishes more.

This is an array formula which will fill a complete row. Then you would just drag it down column B only. I've placed this into a new sheet called "Erik Help," in cell B4:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A4="","",IF(B$3:$3="","",IFERROR(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" "&VLOOKUP(LEFT(B$3:$3,3)&"*",{TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A4,";")),": ",0),"Select Col1")),TEXT(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A4,";")),": ",0),"Select Col2"),"–,",1)),"hh:mm")},IF(VALUE(RIGHT(B$3:$3,1))=1,2,4),FALSE)&"-"&VLOOKUP(LEFT(B$3:$3,3)&"*",{TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A4,";")),": ",0),"Select Col1")),TEXT(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A4,";")),": ",0),"Select Col2"),"–,",1)),"hh:mm")},IF(VALUE(RIGHT(B$3:$3,1))=1,3,5),FALSE)," -",""))))))
```

... then I dragged it to B5 and B6.

NOte: FLATTEN is still an unofficial Google function, so use it with this understanding.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a formula that will automatically fill a column. I don't mind slightly altering each formula in the top row (for each day of the week). I'd like to be able to lock the top row (where all my arrayformulas are). The data entry person doesn't know how to drag formulas and/or forgets to do so when she adds new rows. I'm trying to create a user-error-free solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've added another sheet called "Erik Help 2," based on your added comment. The new array formula you'll find there resides in cell B3 (colored cyan). It populates the entire grid of rows and columns, including the sub-headers (e.g., mon1, mon2, etc.) from that one cell:

```
=ArrayFormula({IF(B$2:O$2<>"",LOWER(LEFT(B$2:O$2,3))&"1",LOWER(LEFT(A$2:N$2,3))&2);IF(TRIM($A4:A)="","",IF(B$2:O$2<>"",
TEXT(TRIM(MID(TRIM($A4:A),FIND(":",TRIM($A4:A),FIND(B$2:O$2,TRIM($A4:A)))+1,9)),"hh:mm")&"-"&TEXT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(TRIM($A4:A),FIND(":",TRIM($A4:A),FIND(B$2:O$2,TRIM($A4:A)))+12,9),",",""),";","")),"hh:mm"),
IF(FIND(";",TRIM($A4:A),FIND(A$2:N$2,TRIM($A4:A)))-FIND(":",TRIM($A4:A),FIND(A$2:N$2,TRIM($A4:A)))>25,
TEXT(TRIM(MID(TRIM($A4:A),FIND(",",TRIM($A4:$A),FIND(A$2:N$2,TRIM($A4:A)))+1,9)),"hh:mm")&"-"&TEXT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(TRIM($A4:A),FIND(",",TRIM($A4:$A),FIND(A$2:N$2,TRIM($A4:A)))+12,9),";","")),"hh:mm"),"")))})
```

You'll want to check it over carefully for accurate results, but it seems right to me.

Keep in mind that this complex formula *relies* on your keeping the current structure in Column A. That is:

1.) Weekdays are spelled out and followed by a colon and space.

2.) Two periods in the same day are separated by a comma.

3.) *Every* weekday's entry ends with a semicolon.

If you change this setup, the formula will not work, because it will not be able to find the markers it needs.